# C# Dynamically load assemblies

Tags: c#, dynamic, load, assemblies

I have a solution with many concrete implementations each in their own class library which all implement one of four main interfaces that I have built.  I have also created a factory object for each interface to dynamically load the requested object.  i.e.

```
public static IDataIngestorFormat GetDataIngestionFormat(string typeName, IDataIngestor di)
{
        Type format = Type.GetType(typeName);
        object formatInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(format, di);
        IDataIngestorFormat instance = formatInstance as IDataIngestorFormat;
        return instance;
}
```

Everything is working as expected until I come to the usage of these objects.  I have a some unit test projects for each of the interfaces and concrete objects as well as a WCF REST service and an API layer that require access however will fail on the CreateInstance unless I copy the concrete objects (with a Post Build Event) to the output path of each of these client projects which are in the same solution.

Now for my question - this approach works, but I would prefer to not have to remember to add these in to all of my client projects every time I create a new concrete implementation.

Is there an easy way to achieve this or am I going to have to remember to visit all of my client projects every time I add a new concrete implementation?

Comment: can't you embed them as resources?

Comment: Note that you are likely recreating at least one of following: [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [dependency injection frameworks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) like Unity. Consider using existing libraries for configuring/managing your runtime dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - hadn't heard of MEF but on first look this looks very interesting.  Didn't know about the possibility of adding as resources either, but I guess with this approach I would still need to visit each client application?

Comment: Alexei,  your comment is spot on - MEF / DI look to be perfect for this. Feel free to put this as an answer and I we mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a naming convention to guarantee unique names for each client assembly and related unit test assemblies, then just change the build output path so everything builds into a top level build directory.